# Django Db Images video

Tags: database, django, image, store

How can I store Images, Videos and Audio via Django in a Mysql db?

I know I can either store the link to the image, video, audio, or the image, video, audio itself.

But how does this exactly work.

I know about the models and how they create tables via the manage.py. 
But is there a good tutorial on how to create an image (e.g. jpg, tiff etc) database via Django.

Thanks

L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel is referring to the fact that storing large binary files in a DB is not efficient. Use the filesystem instead - take a look at FileField and ImageFileField, which are designed to handle file uploads:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield

The only thing stored in the DB is the path to the binary file.

Answer (score 5):

The Model you need models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    file= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
```

Form class you need forms.py

```
from .models import Video

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Video
        fields= ["name", "file"]
```

inside views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Video
from .forms import VideoForm

def showvideo(request):

    firstvideo= Video.objects.last()

    videofile= firstvideo.file.url


    form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context= {'file_url': videofile,
              'form': form
              }

    return render(request, 'videos.html', context)
```

And finally your template: videos.html

```
<body>

<h1>Video Uploader</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<br>
<video width='600' controls>
    <source src='{{ file_url }}' type='video/mp4'>
    File not found.
</video>
<br>
</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a tutorial on this. Django doesn't support it out of the box, and it's horribly inefficient. Don't do it.

Comment: ? So how do you create a image database in django? 
What would be the very efficient way to do that? 
How can you create a site where all your images would be shown. 
As a project to learn django?
Your answer was not very helpful.

Comment: @MacPython you use the file system, where in Django you can use the FileField which will be relative path in the database to the file on your file system.